# Port forwarding using iptables on Linux

Tags: networking, iptables

I want to forward a local port to a remote port (8041) to a port (8042) on a remote machine (10.0.0.42). I can do this via

```
ssh -L 10.0.0.41:8041:10.0.0.42:8042 user@localhost
```

where `10.0.0.41` is bound to `eth0`.

Now I want to do this without all the userland and encryption overhead.

My guess would be

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d 10.0.0.41 --dport 8041 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.42:8042
```

and enable ip-forward - but it does not work.

Comment: Did you add a masquerade rule? `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an SNAT rule as well.

Right now, you have this:

```
Client ---> NAT box ---> Server
  /|\                       |
   |                       /
    \_____________________/
```

That won't work; the client is unaware of the NAT, and so it'll be confused when the reply comes directly from the server. So you need to make the server see the NAT box as the source—which you do by adding a SNAT rule.

```
Client <---> NAT box <---> Server
```

Comment: Just as additional info: Technically that methodology (the return going directly to the client) can work, but it requires using IPVS (via tools such as `ipvsadm`).

Comment: @Patrick sure, it also requires some cooperation from the server, I believe.

Comment: You are correct, it does (adding an IP to the loopback interface and a few sysctl params) :-)